# How to redirect to remote server web page from another java application using POST request

Tags: javascript, java, php, jquery, forms

I have a requirement wherein I have to send a POST request from my java web application to another remote server and the only information I have of the other remote server is the way they submit their request which is as follows:

```
<form action = "https://xyz.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name=" param1 "  value="$param1" />
    <input type="hidden" name=" param2 "  value=" param2" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I tried sending the request through "HTTPURLConnection" and I am able to get the response code 200 which is OK. But the main thing I want to do is to open the remote server web page on the new tab.I am not able to make out how to do that. Please provide your valuable inputs

Answer (score 0):

did n't quite sure what you ask for

`<form action = "https://xyz.php" method="post" target="_blank"`>

it is used to open in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var frm = $('<form   method="get" action="' + link + '" target="_blank"></form>')
$("body").append(frm);
frm.submit().remove();
```

From jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b039wc1h/93/